# PostgreSQL COUNT DISTINCT on one column while checking duplicates of another column

Tags: postgresql, count, distinct, postgresql-9.1

I have a query that results in such a table:

```
guardian_id | child_id | guardian_name | relation | child_name |
------------|----------|---------------|----------|------------|
    1       |   1      | John Doe      | father   | Doe Son    |
    2       |   1      | Jane Doe      | mother   | Doe Son    |
    3       |   2      | Peter Pan     | father   | Pan Dghter |
    4       |   2      | Pet Pan       | mother   | Pan Dghter |
    1       |   3      | John Doe      | father   | Doe Dghter |
    2       |   3      | Jane Doe      | mother   | Doe Dghter |
```

So from these results, I need to count the families. That is, distinct children with the same guardians. From the results above, There are 3 children but 2 families. How can I achieve this?

If I do:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT child_id) as families FROM (
  //larger query
)a
```

I'll get 3 which is not correct.
Alternatively, how can I incorporate a `WHERE` clause that checks `DISTINCT` guardian_id's? Any other approaches?

Also note that there are instances where a child may have one guardian only.

Comment: Are you really still using Postgres 9.1? That has been out of support for [over two years now)(https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). You should plan your upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Yes, the system is heavily reliant on postgres 9.1 (multiple applications using the same RDBMS (postgres 9.1)- as for the upgrade, other more senior members of the team have the say on that

Answer (score 1):

To get the distinct family you can try the following approach.

```
select distinct array_agg(distinct guardian_id) 
from family
group by child_id;
```

The above query will return the list of unique families.
eg.

```
{1,2}
{3,4}
```

Now you can apply the count on top of it.